# How to group ssrs report with a group

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have a resultset from stored procedure.

```
Id   ShortName      yValue    xValue    Sum

1     A           Place1     -3       10.02
1     B           Place1     -3       9.5
1     Diff        Place1     -3       .52
2     C           Place2     -3       7.62
2     D           Place2     -3       8.50
2     Diff        Place2     -3       -0.88
```

I need to display this result in SSRS as shown below

```
            A       B     Diff
 Place1    10.02  9.5     .52


           C       D      Diff
Place2    7.62    8.50    -.88.
```

Could you please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this and I am glad to share with you.

To separate a report into two, we need a column which distinguish them. Here i have Id column which distinguish two reports. So I have created a row group bu the following steps.

**Row Groups**> Right click and select **Add group**>**Parent group**>   **Group by**> Select Id(column name) .Done.

Then press F4 for properties ,expand **Group** > expand **PageBreak** > set **Break location** as **Start**.

This will give the reports in different worksheet. If you need to set custom worksheet name, then set in **PageName** property.

Hope it will help you.